# How to use flutter plugin, that I created, in my flutter app as local plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I have created a flutter plugin for android and ios and I want to use that plugin in my flutter app locally. I don't want to upload it to pub.dev but to use it locally in my flutter app. I searched a bit and I found that I can use external packages locally but I didn't find anything about a plugin. These are directories under my plugin package **all_pdf_tools**:

[image]

Out of these which directory do I need to move to my flutter app directory and then how should I declare it to use it in my pubspec.yaml and then how can I use my plugin's methods in the flutter app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your Flutter app and plugin are in sibling folders.

The add a dependency in `pubspec.yaml` of your Flutter app:

```
dependencies:
  all_pdf_tools:
    path: ../all_pdf_tools
```

This tells your Flutter project to look for your plugin at the relative path, rather than in `pub` or a local git repo.

(If you look in `all_pdf_tools/example/pubspec.yaml` you'll see this is how the example app refers to its plugin by using `path: ../`)

Comment: Means I'll have to copy paste this all_pdf_tools directory into my flutter app directory

Comment: Do I need these example and test directories?

Comment: No - into an adjacent folder - e.g. /projects/my_app and /projects/my_plugin (and you can use a more complicated relative path if you want, too, if they aren't adjacent)

Comment: And also how can I call the methods of this plugin (like one method is encryptPDF) from my flutter app

Comment: `import 'package:all_pdf_tools/all_pdf_tools.dart';`

Comment: I will give it a try and will update you by tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked perfectly. I just made a plugins directory in my flutter app and moved my plugin into that directory. Now its path: plugins/all_pdf_tools. I think that's ok to do right?

Comment: It might, but it would make more sense to put them side by side, rather than one inside the other.